# Cross Platform C++ UI Application

Tags: c++, linux, encryption, cross-platform, smartcard

Actually I'm a very good windows application developer with experience in several languages. I'm so good C++ developer also.
I got a question, I used to use Visual Studio all of my life, from VS 6.0 to now VS 2013. I've never wrote big UI app for Linux or Mac, some basic command line based (mostly) apps for Linux (ubuntu) and Mac OSX.

Now I want to create an application which will deal with smart cards, USB, crypto, files, internet. I want to make it cross platform. I can write whole app in VS 2012 with C++ and MFC in just 5 days (it's not a big project, just some basic things), but I have to make it cross platform and all of them should be same in UI, functionality and everything.

So what you cross-platform developers suggest? I have to design UI and UI should look pretty, I already have CodeJock license, but I don't think I can use it for Linux, so I need a way to be able to write cross platform app which will also deal with OS specific things, like my app will have a tray icon, will work with files and smart card API.

How it's possible to write such code, which IDE, which UI designer?
Thanks!

Comment: try Qt library. This will provide you platform independent environment. It is similarly stupid as MFC:) but is by two decades more modern:)

Comment: How does it work? For example how I can add "cross-platform" system tray icon? or how can I work with Smart Card API or USB interface or internet APIs cross-platform? Do I have to have different functions per OS?

Comment: But you are quite a bad Googler, aren't you?

Comment: I want to know how to write cross-platform codes and UIs, how to add cross-platform system tray icon or access smart card and USB interface. Do I have to write OS specific functions or there is better way?

Comment: @V-X In what way is Qt *"similarly stupid as MFC"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a great deal of possibilities that you can look at. One that I have had one of the greatest experiences with is the Simple Directmedia Layer. It doesn't come with a drag-and-drop graphics designer like Visual Studio (Is that what you mean by 'UI designer'?). However its api is fairly powerful and as its based off of OpenGL it works on all major platforms. I can't say how it compares to CodeJock as I have never used CodeJock. As for an IDE, Code::Blocks is a very powerful, cross-platform, and open-source C/C++ IDE. Both of these are free software to use, see their individual licensing for more information. As for the specific features you wish to incorporate in your program a quick Google search will turn up a very large amount of tutorials that you can use.

Code::Blocks: http://www.codeblocks.org/

Simple Directmedia Layer: http://www.libsdl.org/

I hope this helps,

Sincerely,

Chris

P.S. If you have any more questions feel free to ask. I remember when I started programming cross-platform, it was difficult but one of the best decisions I ever made.

Comment: I want to know how to write cross-platform codes and UIs, how to add cross-platform system tray icon or access smart card and USB interface. Do I have to write OS specific functions or there is better way?

Comment: Due to the cross-platform nature you should be able to use the same code and make use of C++'s WOCA attribute. (Write Once Compile Anywhere) I wish you the best of luck, persevere and you shall succeed.

Comment: Thank you Chris, but can you tell me more about WOCA? I mean, CodeBlocks does have such thing or it's not related to IDE, it's related to some libraries?

Comment: WOCA is a just a 'feature' of C++ if you will. It means that C++ runs in native code instead of a VM as a language like Java does. (Java is a WORA/WORE, Write Once Run Anywhere/Everywhere.) This means that a WOCA language needs to be compiled for each platform that it will be running on. A WORA however only needs to be compiled once and it can run on any machine that has its VM installed. I hope this isn't to confusing...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_compile_anywhere

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once,_run_anywhere

Comment: I got WOCA and WORA, thank you again! For example when I want to use Windows Smart Card API, how can I write a function which will work in Windows and Linux?

Comment: I honestly have utilized the Windows Smart Card API. If it is made by Microsoft for windows then there is a good chance they made it in-compatible with other operating systems. You can check Google for more information and possibly a work-around.

Comment: so for functions like smart card or for system tray icon, does QT or Ultimate++ handle them or I have to write several functions and based on OS it's compiling in, compiler will switch between functions with #define ?

Comment: @user3093013 If it's not supported by your main framework, it's better to write your own abstraction (or find another portable library) to abstract the smartcard interface, instead of starting another `#define`, `#ifdef`, ... hell.

Comment: @g-makulik and Chris, thank you both. I learned what I wanted.

Comment: You are very welcome. 

Like I said previously, I remember what it is like transitioning from windows-only code to cross-platform. Just don't give up and you won't regret it.